# Как обособить вводное слово в присоединительной конструкции?

Tags: вводные-слова

"Не так страшны совсем мелкие опечатки или тонкие пунктуационные моменты, как явная небрежность — сюда же незакрытые кавычки или скобки, например".

Является часть этого предложения после тире присоединительной конструкцией?

Если это присоединительная конструкция, то в случае использования тире при ее обособлении ставится запятая перед вводным "например" (как в приведенном случае), а если бы присоединение обособлялось запятой, а не тире, то вводное уже не обособлялось бы запятой по правилу необособления вводного в начале или конце обособленного оборота?

То есть во втором случае было бы правильно так писать: "Не так страшны совсем мелкие опечатки или тонкие пунктуационные моменты, как явная небрежность, сюда же незакрытые кавычки или скобки например.

Часто в текстах в интернете после вводных "в частности" и "например", стоящих  в начале оборота, обособленного тире, ставится запятая.

Например:

"Но там важнее другие аспекты — например, не долговременная память, а оперативная".

Comment: Это не присоединительный оборот, потому что глагол уже другой: *сюда же [можно отнести] незакрытые кавычки или скобки, например*. А правило относится только к присоединительным оборотам, не ко всем присоединительным конструкциям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словосочетание "сюда же" и слово "например" в исходном тексте противоречат друг другу. *Сюда же* указывает, что незакрытые кавычки и скобки **не относятся** к явным небрежностям.
Напротив слово *например* указывает на то, что эти кавычки и скобки один из вариантов явной небрежности. По смыслу фразы незакрытые кавычки или скобки это действительно явная небрежность. Поэтому словосочетание "сюда же" безусловно должно быть удалено.
Получается, что было бы правильно писать: "Не так страшны совсем мелкие опечатки или тонкие пунктуационные моменты, как явная небрежность, незакрытые кавычки или скобки например.

Comment: Почему указывает, что не относятся? Перед тире же нет запятой. Это значит, что относится к обороту. Потом: обороты с "как" не относятся к присоединительным оборотам, они в другой теме (это насчёт вашего варианта).

Comment: Ну нельзя же забывать про семантику, от этого и пунктуация может стать ошибочной. «Сюда же» эквивалентно «кроме того». И получатся что логическая структура фраза аналогична такой: В сарай свалили рухлядь, сюда же попал велосипед. Здесь велосипед не рухлядь. А при использовании «например» получается: В сарай свалили рухлядь, велосипед например. А здесь велосипед рухлядь. То есть исходный текст логически противоречивый, и эту ошибку надо исправить. 
P.S. Слово «как» относится не к моему варианту, а к исходному тексту.

Comment: Здесь современное употребление. Очень часто так используется. Смысл: *в это число [к ним] можно отнести*. Тоже так употребляю. У вас "например" в обороте с "как", запятую надо. Они не присоединительные.

Comment: При Вашем понимании "сюда же", оно и "например" имеют одинаковый смысл. Стиль  исходного предложения не допускает дублирования, поэтому "сюда же" надо удалить,  за двусмысленность.  Заодно уберем недопустимый стилистический выкрутас с "например" в конце.  Получится: " ... как явная небрежность, например, незакрытые кавычки или скобки. ПМСМ сначала надо исправить текст семантически, грамматически и стилистически, а уж потом править пунктуацию.

Comment: Не имеют одинаковый смысл (*сюда относятся незакрытые кавычки или скобки, например*). Не вижу никакой двусмысленности, от слова совсем. Если удалять, то "например", потому что в "сюда же" вся фишка, у него своеобразная стилистика (типа изюминка). И "или" лучше заменить на "и", потому что здесь объединение, а не выбор. То же в начале. Что-то не так понял ваш вариант, там правильно, показалось, что там что-то типа "как незакрытые кавычки или скобки например".

Comment: (**сюда относятся** незакрытые кавычки или скобки, **например**). Уберите любой из выделенных фрагментов, и смысл всего предложения не изменится. Значит это дубликаты.  
Вы - «сюда же» указывает, что скобки-кавычки пример явной небрежности. Я - «сюда же» указывает, что скобки-кавычки пример невнимательности, а не явной небрежности. Значит для нас с Вами «сюда же» двусмысленное выражение.  
… **изюминка** … Всё предложение написано в стиле методички или инструкции. Эти документы должны быть максимально понятны. А стилистические изыски с дублированием нормальный редактор вычеркнет.

Comment: Не совсем, "например" указывает, что эти вещи названы для примера. Не двусмысленное, потому что по запятой определяется, к чему относится. Ваш вариант, если запятая перед тире. Не инструкция. Они о том, как что-то сделать, а здесь просто говорится. А методичка — это уже не документ. Да, они не очень стыкуются, потому что "сюда же" используется для подчёркивания (**целенаправленная** подача информации), для обращения внимания (*замечу, что сюда относится...*), что-то типа "в частности" (но слабее), а "например" означает, что никакого акцента нет (просто для примера; **случайная** информация).

Comment: Извините, мы с Вами говорим на разных языках: я - на семантическом, Вы - на пунктуационном. Нас не понять друг друга. Извините за беспокойство

Comment: Ну так пунктуация помогает понять семантику (что к чему относится).